# What is the difference between "por si" and "por si acaso"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

I learned that "just in case" should be translated *por si acaso*, but I have also heard *por si* used by itself without the *acaso*. I believe I've even heard *si acaso* without the *por*. What is the difference? Is it just stylistic, or are the cases where you must use one or the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, the three combinations have different meanings:

- *Por si acaso* is an expression which adequately translates *just in case*.
- *Por si* **might be** a shortening of *por si acaso*. Perhaps you heard *por si las moscas*, and couldn't make sense of it. That is a slang variation of *por si acaso*. A couple of examples where it is used as a shortening of *por si acaso* are:

> Voy a hacer (algo) **por si** (algo).
>
> Cerraré la puerta con llave **por si** hay ladrones merodeando.
>
> Ahorré dinero **por si** llegaba la crisis económica.
>   
>   However, I believe this is not a correct use of the language, though it might be common in some places. It doesn't sound right to me, at least.

- Similarly, *si acaso* sounds like a slang variation and not entirely correct (actually, it sounds worse than *por si*).

> Cerraré la puerta **si acaso** hay ladrones merodeando.
>
> **Si acaso** vienes a visitarme, cocinaré pavo para ti.

Comment: I noticed "Si Acaso Vuelves" is the name of a Vicente Fernandez song (and I'm pretty sure I've heard it in a different song as well).

Comment: Si acaso is incorrect in this context. But it is correct in other contexts.