# ¿Origen de la expresión "Por si la mosca"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, origen

Ayer ví en un divertido video de tiktok que la expresión en inglés "Just in case" se puede traducir al español como "por si la mosca".  Se puede ver la misma en google translate (pero yo sé que google no es el mejor traductor)

¿De dónde viene esa expresión?  ¿Por qué "moscas"? (¿Y es google correcto?)

Ví esta pregunta que también esta usando "la moscas".  Pero no sé por qué hay moscas: [What does "Sacudirse alguien las moscas" mean?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/36985/4251). Sin embargo, pienso que  sea una conexión entre las dos expresiones.

Pero, esta pregunta no menciona moscas en absoluto: [What is the difference between "por si" and "por si acaso"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1692/4251)

Comment: @今夜九 He visto los dos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> El origen de la expresión surgió de la costumbre de cubrir los alimentos y bebidas con algún tipo de paño o algo que los tapase (cuando no existían las neveras y se guardaban en las despensas), para impedir que las moscas se posaran sobre ello y se estropeara, además de evitar contraer alguna enfermedad, en los tiempos en los que se tenía el convencimiento de que la mayoría de infecciones y enfermedades eran transmitidas por los insectos.

<sub>*Párrafo extraído de [¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión 'por si las moscas'?](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-por-si-las-moscas/) del periódico 20 minutos*</sub>

> ... algún lingüista ha sugerido que el modismo evoca un pasaje del Antiguo Testamento. De las diez plagas que Yahvé lanzó sobre Egipto para obligar al faraón a liberar al pueblo judío, una era de moscas, y así habrían devenido en símbolo de cualquier eventualidad funesta. De ahí el “por si las moscas”, para evitar que nos pase como a Ramsés II (c. 1279-c. 1213 a. C.).

<sub>*Párrafo extraído de [¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión 'por si las moscas'?](https://www.lavanguardia.com/historiayvida/mas-historias/20221005/8549091/cual-origen-expresion-moscas-pmv.html#:%7E:text=De%20las%20diez%20plagas%20que,1213%20a.) del periódico La Vanguardia*</sub>